# Implementing a queue using a linked-list

Tags: c, linked-list, queue

In my intro CS class we're reviewing data structures. I'm currently working on implementing a queue using a linked list (FIFO) in C. I'd appreciate a review of the implementation as well as of my understanding of how a queue should work

```
// This program is implementation of queue data structure
// via linked list (FIFO)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int number;
    struct node *next;
} node;


node *enqueue(int element, node *temp);
node *dequeue(int n, node *temp);
void display(node *temp);
void destroy_queue(node *temp);

int main()
{
    node *queue = NULL;

    // add some elements to queue
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        queue = enqueue((i + 1), queue);
    }


    // display queue
    display(queue);

    // dequeue 2 elements from queue
    printf("Removing two elements from queue...\n");
    queue = dequeue(2, queue);

    //display queue
    display(queue);

    // free memory
    destroy_queue(queue);

}

node *enqueue(int element, node *temp)
{
    node *newElement = malloc(sizeof(node));
    node *head = temp;
    if (newElement == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "No memory for the new queue element");
        return temp;
    }

    newElement->number = element;
    newElement->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        return newElement;
    }
    else
    {
        while ((temp->next) != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = newElement;
    }
    return head;
}

node *dequeue(int n, node *temp)
{
    node *aux;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (!temp)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"No elements to remove!");
            return temp;
        }
        aux = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        temp = aux;
    }
    return temp;
}

void display(node *temp)
{
    while (temp)
    {
        printf("Elements in queue are: %i\n", temp->number);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

void destroy_queue(node *temp)
{
    node *aux = temp;
    while (temp)
    {
        aux = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        temp = aux;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Having a separate `queue` structure

  ```
  typedef struct {
      node * head;
      node * tail;
  } queue;
  ```

  will bring you several benefits:

  - Most important, `enqueue` would take a constant time (vs linear in queue length you have now).
  - The client would be relieved from responsibility to maintain the head node.
  - `enqueue` doesn't inform the client that it failed the allocation. `fprintf` is good for the human, but does nothing for the calling routine. Having the `queue` structure enables you to return an error code.
- The specialized utility functions, like `enqueue` and `dequeue` should not print anything. They must communicate success/error to the caller, and let it act appropriately.
- `else` in `enqueue` is redundant.
- I don't see why do you `#include <string.h>`.

Comment: Constant time `enqueue()` and `dequeue()` does not require 2 pointers in `queue`.  One is sufficient.  Simple have member `.tail` and let the tail of the queue point to the head.  Adding to either end of queue is `O(1)`  Removing from the head is also `O(1)`.

Comment: @chux Right. Circular queue is better. I was pondering that as well, but decided against for purely didactical reasons.